# How can I install DBD::Pg if postgres is not installed?

Tags: linux, perl, perl-module, nagios

I have a separate servers running with postgres and Nagios. I want to use "**psql_replication_check.pl**" with nagios to monitor the postgres replication status. This check script requires DBD::Pg module to connect to database. Installation of DBD::Pg asking for the path of pg_config file.

```
#perl Makefile.PL 
Configuring DBD::Pg 2.17.1
Path to pg_config?
```

I don't have permissions to install postgres on Nagios machine. Is there anyone who has fixed this issue before.

I have CentOS 5.4 on both systems.

Comment: What linux distribution or packaging system?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you need in order to install `DBD::Pg` isn't all of PostgreSQL, but only the C client library, `libpq`. The package containing the header files for that will also include the `pg_config` program. On most Debian-based systems, that package is called `libpq-dev` - other vendors will have other names for it.

Comment: Thanks Rafl: may i request you to please advise where i can get this for linux 32 bit.

Comment: How about from the vendor of your Linux distribution?

Comment: For Centos or Fedora see http://serverfault.com/questions/316703/how-to-install-libpq-dev-on-centos-5-5, and for me this worked on Fedora 10: `yum install postgresql-devel`